# Why the absolute temperature used in radiation equation of Stefan Boltzmann law ?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why the absolute temperature used in radiation equation of Stefan Boltzmann law ?

Comment: What else were you be expecting? Can you expand a bit on exactly what your confusion is?

Answer (score 1):

Because the formula is a lot simpler that way. If you'd use Celsius instead of absolute temperatures, you'd get all 4 lower-order terms as well.

Comment: And they'd involve various powers of $273.15$ as well.